# Completeness for pure arithmetical sentences?

Tags: first-order-logic, incompleteness

Is it possible the define an effectively generated first order axiomatic system that is complete for pure arithmetical sentences defined in its language?

A pure arithmetical sentences is a sentence using the traditional arithmetical operators (including $\neq, <, > $) but that doesn't use any logical connective!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "complete" ?

Comment: It means that every pure arithmetical sentence in its language is either provable or disprovable in it.

Comment: Just for clarity about what information you are asking for, if someone showed you how to encode arithmetic statements containing boolean gates as arithmetic statements without them, would that be enough to answer your question as "no" ?  Or would you need more or something different?

Comment: @DanielV, you need to get rid of the quantifiers as well. In nutshell if you can encode all arithmetic sentences using pure arithmetic sentences for example in PA, then of course that would answer the above question to the negative.

Comment: In the standard terminology, a sentence is a formula with no free variables. Is that what you mean by sentence? If so, then a finite system like Robinson's $Q$ is enough. (See Noah's answer for more details.)

Comment: @RobArthan, No. I'm speaking of quantifier free sentences.

Comment: So your "sentences" can have free variables? If so, it's the second part of Noah's answer that applies (*mutatis mutandis* to allow for your non-standard use of the term "sentence").

Answer (score 1):

In fact we can do much better: Robinson's $\mathsf{Q}$ proves every true $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence *(this is called $\Sigma^0_1$-completeness - see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258431/who-first-proved-that-we-can-prove-that-we-prove-things-we-prove))* and so a fortiori decides every quantifier-free sentence. It seems to me that your "purely arithmetical" sentences are in particular all quantifier-free, so this is more than enough.

If we try to go much beyond the quantifier-free sentences, however, things quickly break down: by the internal MRDP theorem (see [Hajek/Pudlak section I.3(d)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235421930)), no consistent computably axiomatizable extension of $I\Sigma_1$ can decide every sentence of the form "Such-and-such Diophantine equation has no solutions." Note that we don't even need any Booleans here - universally quantified equations are enough to be problematic.

Comment: at which page Hajek/Pudlak section is?

Comment: @Zuhair As I said, it's section I.3(d) (that section is only one page long, namely page $97$): every $\Sigma_1$ sentence is $I\Sigma_1$-provably equivalent to an $\exists$-sentence (and the conversion from $\exists$-sentences to sentences asserting the existence of solutions to Diophantine equations is straightforward, not sure why they don't mention it there).

Comment: That said, for completeness here's a proof of the most nontrivial bit. Suppressing free variables for the moment (they'll come back later), consider a formula of the form "$S=T$ has a *non*-solution;" we want to find new polynomials $S', T'$ such that that statement is equivalent to "$S'=T'$ has a solution." To do this, note that a non-solution to $S=T$ corresponds to a solution to one of $S+u+1=T$ or $S=T+u+1$ where $u$ is some new variable. Over $\mathbb{Z}$ we'd use subtraction here as follows: $S=T$ has a non-solution iff there is some $u$ such that $$(S+u+1-T)(S-T-u-1)=0$$ has a solution.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{N}$ we just expand everything out and move the negative terms across the equality. This gives us a pair of new terms $S',T'$ in the original variables $x_1,...,x_n$ plus a new variable $u$ such that $$\exists x_1,...,x_n(S\not=T)\mbox{ is equivalent to } \exists x_1,...,x_n,u(S'=T')$$ as desired. The remaining cases are easy to handle (e.g. "$S_1=T_1$ and $S_2=T_2$ have simultaneous solutions" is equivalent to "$(S_1-T_1)^2+(S_2-T_2)^2=0$ has a solution" - or its negatives-moved-across counterpart if you care about $\mathbb{N}$ versus $\mathbb{Z}$).